# sprite looks like triangle

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

private Camera mCamera;
    private Scene mMainScene;

```
private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private TextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
}
@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {
    mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 32, 32);
    mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_box.png", 0, 0);
    mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();

}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger()); 


    this.mMainScene = new Scene();
    this.mMainScene.setBackground(new Background(1, 1, 1));

    final int iStartX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - mBitmapTextureAtlas.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int iStartY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - mBitmapTextureAtlas.getHeight()) / 2;


    final Sprite oPlayer = new Sprite(iStartX, iStartY, mPlayerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.mMainScene.attachChild(oPlayer);

}
```

My sprite looks like it is cut in half. Can somebody explain why?
And background color is still black and it should be white.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the scene in your onCreateScene() method.
And you said that your sprite looks like it is cut in half, may be your image size is bigger than your bitmaptextureAtlas. If so, increase your textureAtlas size.

Comment: Agreed - but also call the pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();